# Replace strings column with dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign the dictionary key to a string column so the strings will have more consistent formats. If the string cannot be found in the dict key, we can either remove it or assign it as NaN. I tried using `map(keys())` but it's not working. How can I do this effectively?

```
fruit_dict = {
  "Apple": ["Apple", "apple", "apple_cake"],
  "Watermelon": ["Watermelon", "water_melon"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2],
        "name": [
            "apple, water_melon",
            "apple_cake, cherry"
        ],
    }
)

   ID                name
0   1  apple, water_melon
1   2  apple_cake, cherry
```

Expected output:

```
   ID               name
0   1  Apple, Watermelon
1   2              Apple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to reverse keys and values from `fruit_dict` to create a reverse mapping. Then explode your dataframe to have one word per row and reassemble your dataframe to get the original shape.

```
mapping = {v: k for k, l in fruit_dict.items() for v in l}

df['name'] = df['name'].str.split(', ').explode().map(mapping).dropna() \
                       .groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)
print(df)

# Output:
   ID               name
0   1  Apple, Watermelon
1   2              Apple
```

Details:

```
>>> mapping
{'Apple': 'Apple',
 'apple': 'Apple',
 'apple_cake': 'Apple',
 'Watermelon': 'Watermelon',
 'water_melon': 'Watermelon'}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you!